# Need to prove formula for $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{k} z^{2^k}}{1 + z^{2^k}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I need help showing that for $|z|<1$ we have

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{k} z^{2^k}}{1 + z^{2^k}}$ = $\frac{z}{1-z}$

I tried using $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-z^{2^k})^{n} = \frac{1}{1+z^{2^k}}$ but that hasn't gotten me very far. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: [Cauchy Condensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) can help get bounds on your sum (and therefore show convergence), but won't get you equality yet.

Comment: The problem before this had me show that for $|z|<1$ we have $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{2^{k-1}}}{1-z^{2^k}} = \frac{z}{1-z}$ I hope this also helps!

Comment: Same thing I did above. I put $\frac{1}{1-z^{2^k}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (z^{2^k})^n$. From here you get a double sum of the form $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{2^{n}(2k+1)}$ which equals $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} z^k$. This doesn't help too much though because of the $2^k$ that appears in the new sum.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two different expansions of $\frac{z}{1-z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2170972/two-different-expansions-of-fracz1-z)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define 
$$
f(z)=\frac{z}{z-1}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2^kz^{2^k}}{1+z^{2^k}}
$$
then it is easy to confirm that
$$
2f(z^2)=f(z)\implies f(z)=2^kf(z^{2^k})
$$
Now it is a bit more tedious but still elementary to confirm that for all $r<1$ there is a constant $C_r$ so that for all $|z|<r$
$$
|f(z)|\le C_r |z|.
$$
But then also $|z^{2^k}|<r$ and $2^k|z|^{2^k}\to 0$ for $k\to\infty$ which implies 
$$
f(z)=0
$$
for all $|z|<1$.

---

*Another approach* can use term-wise differentiation 
$$
\frac1{1-z}=\prod_{k=0}^\infty(1+z^{2^k})\\
-\ln(1-z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\ln(1+z^{2^k})\\
\frac1{1-z}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2^kz^{2^k-1}}{1+z^{2^k}}\\
\frac{z}{1-z}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2^kz^{2^k}}{1+z^{2^k}}\\
$$

Comment: (+1) for the second approach, which is clear and concise.

Answer (score 3):

Let 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{k} z^{2^k}}{1 + z^{2^k}} =  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$$
and examine contributions to the $a_n$ from the various terms in the $k$ sum.

For $n=0$ none of the terms in the sum contributes (the $k=0$ contribution is 
$z-z^2+z^3-z^4+\ldots$).

For $n$ odd only the $k=0$ term contributes, and thus for $n$ odd, $a_n = 1$.

The $k=1$ term of the sum contributes to $(-1)^{n/2+1}2^1$ to each $a_n$ for $n$ even.  Higher $k$ terms give no contribution to $a_2$, or indeed to any 
$a_{4p+2}$, thus for $p\in\Bbb Z$
$$
a_{4p+2} = (-1) + 2 = 1 $$
The contributions of the $k=1$ term of the sum to each $a_{4p}$ is $-2$.

The $k=2$ term of the sum contributes to $(-1)^{n/4+1}2^2$ to each $a_n$ for $n$ divisible by $4$.  Higher $k$ terms give no contribution to  any 
$a_{8p+4}$, thus for $p\in\Bbb Z$
$$
a_{8p+4} = (-1) + (-2) + 4 = 1 $$
The contributions of the $k=2$ term of the sum to each $a_{8p}$ is $-4$.

The $k=3$ term of the sum contributes to $(-1)^{n/8+1}2^3$ to each $a_n$ for $n$ divisible by $8$.  Higher $k$ terms give no contribution to  any 
$a_{16p+8}$, thus for $p\in\Bbb Z$
$$
a_{16p+8} = (-1) + (-2) + (-4) + 8 = 1 $$
The contributions of the $k=2$ term of the sum to each $a_{8p}$ is $-8$.

Without going to the effort to formally introduce induction here, we can see the pattern:  For any even $n>0$, the net contributions always add to $1$, and for odd $n$ we already saw a value of $a_n = 1$.  Thus the result
is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty z^n = \frac{z}{1-z}
$$

Comment: Thanks @MarkFischler nice idea! I will be adding that to my bag of tricks!